# Stuck during High Sierra installation and now no startup disk found

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-utility, startup, high-sierra

I was upgrading my MacBook Air from Sierra to High Sierra, but the installation failed and the last line of log window was an error about `directoryd`.

I restarted and then came across the blinking folder with question mark. So I tried recovery mode (Command + R). Disk Utility shows my Macintosh disk properly and there is no problem with it (I checked it with First Aid), but I cannot see any disks on Startup Disk window. what can I do to bring it there?

I have "Install High Sierra.app" on my external drive, can I use it somehow to install the OS?

Answer (score 1):

I used the image to create an USB installer stick of macOS High Sierra and reinstalling the OS solved my problem.